# Deleting rows based upon meeting multiple column conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a very large dataset that I would like to clean up by deleting rows where I have select columns meet the condition of all entries in these column selection being equal to 0. Here is currently what I have:

```
df1 <- filter(df,((n)==0 & (n+1)==0 & (n+2)==0 & (n+3)==0 & ......(n+100)==0)
```

How do I do this so that I delete all row entries that meet this condition for every nth column?

Also, if I wanted to iterate this condition, do I need to state the name of the column?

Here is an example dataset:

```
 A tibble: 10 x 10
 A B C D E F G H I J
 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to remove all rows where F, G & H column are  equal to 0, where my result will be:

```
 A tibble: 10 x 2
 A B C D E F G H I J
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Your question is not reproducible.  Please updated with a small example (just like in my post) sos that I can test it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be `n <- 5; df %>% filter_at(n:(n+100), any_vars(.  != 0))`

Answer (score 0):

One option is `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter_at(11:20, any_vars( .  != 0))
```

A reproducible example

```
df1 %>% 
   filter_at(vars(`11`:`13`), any_vars(. != 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   `11`  `12`  `13` grp  
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     0     4 a    
#2     0     1     0 b
```

Or using `across` from the `devel` version of `dplyr`

```
df1 %>%
    filter(across(cols = matches('^\\d+$'), ~ (.x == 0))) %>% 
    anti_join(df1, .)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   `11`  `12`  `13` grp  
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     0     4 a    
#2     0     1     0 b
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's update, if we have 'n' as some column index and want to filter basedd the columns from that position to the 100 columns after that

```
n <- 5
df %>%
     filter_at(n:(n+100), any_vars(. != 0))
```

#### Update2

```
df2 %>%
   filter_at(vars(F, G, H), any_vars(. != 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 10
#      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
#2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Or using `base R`

```
df2[rowSums(df2[c("F", "G", "H")] != 0) > 0,]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(`11` = c(1, 0, 0), `12` = c(0, 1, 0), `13` = c(4,  0, 0), 
  grp = letters[1:3])





df2 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    B = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L), F = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), H = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), I = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), J = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: when I do this method, i get an error message that says: error in useMethod("tbl_vars")..no applicable method applied to an object or class

Comment: @richierich i guess you are trying to remove rows for those columns having all 0s removed, right. In that case, it is working for me with the upated example

Comment: sorry, I wrote the question in a bad way, please look at my update

Comment: Updated again to add clarity

Comment: @richierich pleasee check my update2.  The code is working fine for me